# Delete 1000 rows from a table that contains 11 million rows takes 24h

Tags: oracle, performance, jdbctemplate

I use the JDBC template to execute the following delete request. It takes a full day to execute.

```sql
DELETE FROM main_events
WHERE  id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id
              FROM   temp_events
              WHERE  ( date + 14 ) < sysdate
                     AND rownum <= 1000)
```

Do you have any suggestions to improve the performance?

Comment: 1. check the plan and make sure it's not using an index on the date column. It should be a full table scan. Check to see that parallel query is enabled for that full table scan. Check to see if parallel dml is enabled (probably not, as you need to alter your session as well as hint the delete). Lastly, if you are deleting a significant portion of the table, consider a `create table as select` to pull out the records you want to *keep* to a temp table, truncate the main table, and insert append back. That's a lot quicker than a delete. Also disable non-unique indexes and then rebuild them later

Comment: Do you at least know which part is slow? Finding the correct IDs in one table, or removing thewm from the other?

Comment: And one more thing, check to see if there are any foreign key constraints referencing the PK or a UK constraint on the table you're deleting. If there are, either disable them or ensure that the constraint columns in the child tables are indexed.

Comment: Another thing is to check that you aren't blocked on a row lock or other concurrency wait and not actually getting anything done at all. A full day to delete 11 million rows seems wildly unreasonable. Something is more seriously wrong than just a bad query plan. It could be unindexed foreign key columns on large child tables, or it could be blocked and going nowhere until the blocking condition is removed. Your DBA should be able to assist you with this.

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing makes little sense.

Comment: There are 3 easy changes that should improve performance. How much, I cannot tell.
1. date + 14 prevents the use of an index on date
2. distinct is killing for performance
3. use EXIST instead of IN; EXIST returns after the first result, IN does not


delete
from     main_events me
where    exists ( select 1
                  from   temp_events te
                  where  te.date < sysdate - 14
                  and    te.id = me.id
                )
and      rownum <= 1000
;

Comment: Thanks all.. identified the issue..for child table index is missing .. After creating index for child table .. we were able to 1.7 crore data in less than 15 mins.